# Is it ok to include garlic when I can hot peppers?

Tags: food-safety, garlic, canning

I followed the Ball Blue Book recipe for canning hot vinegared peppers. I left the peppers whole, and forgot to discard the garlic from the vinegar recipe before I filled the quart size jars & gave them the bath. I made them 10 days ago and I just moved them to the refrigerator because I was scared the garlic would ruin them and possible set them up for the spread of botulism. Are they ruined?

Comment: Vinegar makes it acidic - Acid makes botulism unhappy. You're good.

Answer (score 7):

You should be fine. I couldn't find your particular recipe, but many canning recipes for peppers (and salsas, pickles & relishes) contain garlic. As long as there is sufficient vinegar, which the name of your recipe suggests, and you processed correctly there shouldn't be a problem. This [recipe for Pickled Peppers](http://www.freshpreserving.com/recipes/pickled-peppers) may be similar to yours and contains garlic in the finished product.

Comment: Agree. I've canned asparagus with whole garlic, and as mentioned above, vinegar is the key. You should be fine.